# PyQt5 - Where is QOpenGLWindow?

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, qt5, pyqt5

I did import QOpenGLWindow on command prompt. But QOpenGLWindow can't imported. Where is QOpenGLWindow?

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
>>> QT_VERSION_STR
'5.2.1'
>>> 
>>> from PyQt5.QtGui import QOpenGLWindow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'QOpenGLWindow'
>>>
```

Comment: If we check the docs of Qt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwindow.html, we will see that this class was just introduced in Qt 5.4, so pyqt at least should have introduced it in PyQt 5.4. If you want to use it then update your version of PyQt, the current version in PyQt 5.10

Comment: thanks for comment.

Comment: Since: Qt 5.4
0_o

Comment: I do not understand your comment, it's simple you have a very old version of PyQt that does not support that class.

Comment: yes, that's right. my PyQt is too old.

Comment: <3 
my os is ubuntu14.04. maybe, os version is too old.